# Start lighttpd as root ?

Tags: php, mysql, webserver, lighttpd

Can anyone tell me how can i start lighttpd as root to increase the server.max-fds value ?

According to the lighttpd documentation > http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Server.max-fdsDetails

also, i don't understand what they means by : Changing this setting requires root permissions on startup ???

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You always require root permission to open the ports from 1-1024. Default HTTP-port is 80. In your configuration file you need to add `server.max-fds = 2048` and restart lighttpd as root (prolly the same way you always did). `/etc/init.d/lighttpd restart` in my case.

Answer (score -1):

You can start lighttpd in the background with &-operator from the commandline: lighttpd -D -f configfile &. It works even when you close the shell but I'm using z-shell.